# how to pass outer query's table in inner query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

This is my whole query

```
    SELECT   empmst.emp_id, empmst.emp_name,
         (SELECT RTRIM
                    (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, d || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()').EXTRACT
                                                                   ('//text()'),
                     ','
                    )
            FROM (SELECT TO_DATE ('01-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy') - 1
                         + ROWNUM AS d
                    FROM all_objects
                   WHERE TO_DATE ('01-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy') - 1 + ROWNUM <=
                                          TO_DATE ('30-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
                  MINUS
                  SELECT tsd.ts_date
                    FROM ts_dtl tsd
                   WHERE empmst.emp_id = tsd.emp_id
                     AND tsd.ts_date BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01-04-2012',
                                                      'dd-MM-yyyy'
                                                     )
                                         AND TO_DATE ('30-04-2012',
                                                      'dd-MM-yyyy'
                                                     ))) AS day11
    FROM emp_mst empmst
   WHERE TSD.EMP_ID=EMPMST.EMP_ID
ORDER BY empmst.emp_id
```

I want to pass EMPMST.EMP_ID of the outer query to the inner query but inner query does'nt get EMPMST.EMP_ID in the where clause.
Please tell me how to pass outer query from table to inner query.
Inner query is as follows

```
    (SELECT RTRIM
            (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, d || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()').EXTRACT
                                                                   ('//text()'),
             ','
            )
   FROM (SELECT TO_DATE ('01-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy') - 1 + ROWNUM AS d
           FROM all_objects
          WHERE TO_DATE ('01-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy') - 1 + ROWNUM <=
                                          TO_DATE ('30-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
         MINUS
         SELECT tsd.ts_date
           FROM emp_mst empmst, ts_dtl tsd
          WHERE empmst.emp_id = tsd.emp_id
            AND ts_date BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
                            AND TO_DATE ('30-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy')))
```

I want emp_name and emp_id and TS_date where TS_DATE which are not present in TS_DTL of april means the rest of the days of april which are not there in TS_DTL table

Comment: please post create table queries with some data so that we could run your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below which will achieve the same

```
SELECT EMPMST.EMP_ID,
       EMPMST.EMP_NAME,
       rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, b.d1 || ',')).extract('//text()')
         .extract('//text()'),
         ',') as day11
  from (SELECT TO_DATE('01-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy') - 1 + rownum AS d1
      FROM all_objects
     WHERE TO_DATE('01-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy') - 1 + rownum <=
           TO_DATE('30-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy')) b,
       EMP_MST EMPMST
 WHERE EMPMST.EMAIL_ID IS NOT NULL
   AND EMPMST.DEPT IN ('Technical')
   AND EMPMST.EMP_STATUS_LKP_ID = 201
   AND b.d1 NOT IN
       (SELECT TSD.TS_DATE as d2
      FROM TS_DTL TSD
     WHERE TSD.TS_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy') AND
           TO_DATE('30-04-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
       AND TSD.EMP_ID = EMPMST.EMP_ID)
 ORDER BY EMPMST.EMP_ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the above query gives me all b.d1 values and not the difference of b.d1 and c.d2

Comment: thanks alot ,I added group by EMPMST.EMP_ID,
 EMPMST.EMP_NAME in the above query and its working perfectly.